# Амперсанд в регулярном выражении mysql?

Tags: mysql, регулярные-выражения

Подскажите как заставить работать следующий запрос:

```
select * from test_list where request REGEXP '[[:<:]]test and test (test & test)[[:>:]]'
```

Comment: для начала надо бы знать что вы под этим имели ввиду, т.е. чего вы пытаетесь достичь

Comment: Потому что в данный момент вы написали выражение, которое можно было бы написать просто как `request='test and test test & test'` т.е. это точное соответствие конкретной строке

Comment: в базе в поле request в одной из записей есть значение "test and test (test & test)". Мне нужно найти в базе запись. Точное совпадение.

Comment: А зачем вам тогда regexp, оператор `=` точное соответствие ищет гораздо лучше

Comment: через оператор =. работает, но только если в запросе нет амперсанда.

Comment: А не записал ли у вас амперсанд в базу как &amp; ?

Comment: А не записал ли у вас амперсанд в базу как &amp; ? - нет

Comment: а как вы обращаетесь к mysql? через что?

Comment: https://clip2net.com/s/44uUwko

Comment: phpmyadmin может показывать что ему вздумается, в том числе символом амперсанда обозначать совершенно разные его написания. БД стоит посмотреть консольным mysql или mysqlworkbench. Так же обратить особое внимание на тип поля и отсутствие в значении пробелов в конце. лучше вообще сделать `select hex(request) from table` и по ascii кодам символов убедиться что в строке именно то, что вы видите на экране

Comment: hex от вашей строки выглядит как `7465737420616E6420746573742028746573742026207465737429` если запрос покажет что то иное, смотрите отличия по кодам ascii

Answer (score 0):

Проблема вашей регулярки не в амперсанде, а в том, что вы не экранируете скобки, которые являются специальным символом для регулярок

```
select * from test_list where request REGEXP '^test and test \\(test & test\\)$'
```

Comment: Без скобок тоже не работает.

Comment: в смысле без скобок? вы так запустили, как у меня в ответе? у меня работает

Comment: select * from test_list where request REGEXP '[[:<:]]test & test[[:>:]]'
ваш запрос тоже не сработал. вернул 0 строк.

Comment: а вот такое находит - `^test and test \\(test`

Comment: https://c2n.me/44uUwko

Comment: странно. в phpmyadmin, ваш запрос действительно работает. через yii2 не хочет почему-то...

Comment: Наверное он экранирует. Както сырой запрос можно отправить или посмотреть, какой запрос он формирует